# Do I need to make my Windows 8 install disk bootable when using boot camp?

Tags: bootcamp, bootable-disk, iso

I have the Windows 8 consumer preview .iso which I plan to copy to a DVD to use with Boot Camp. Though my question is - when I burn the image to the disk, will I need to make the disk bootable to use it to install Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Burn it with Disk Utility by adding ISO file to left pane, then choose it and press Burn on a toolbar. And that is it.